# SP 2013 - Search results are displayed in the main page, but not displayed in the sub sites

Tags: search, search-results

SharePoint 2013 - Search results are displayed in the main page, but not displayed in the sub sites. Under sub-site search settings I have selected "Use the same results page settings as my parent." still there are no results.

Getting the below error:

> Nothing here matches your search. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the answer myself. It was an issue in Alternate access mappings. when I moved my Internal Url of Search centre from "Internet" zone into "Default" Zone it started working.

Comment: Always use the Default zone for search. Search Settings, Search Content Sources, etc.